# Unnecessary linked libraries in linker

Tags: c++, linker

I have a project which I can exclude some of libraries from linker and still builds ?

Is it any better to exclude them in terms of the performance and memory of final product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding some unused libraries from the final executable might make startup a bit faster and save a *tiny* amount of memory - chances are only the header and library startup code will actually end up being loaded, and these can be paged out after startup.

However, don't do it manually. If you were told to add the library there's probably a reason for it - perhaps some function call you're not using *yet* requires it, and later on if you use that function call you may have forgotten about it.

Most linkers have an option to exclude unused libraries automatically, so you may want to just enable that option to have it take care of things for you.

Note: In some rare cases, the library's startup code might have some important effect, in which case you should not exclude it. This is something that is best determined by checking the library's documentation; things like this should (hopefully!) be clearly documented.

Answer (score 6):

A good c++ linker would not include any calls from any libs that are not used in the code (the so-called ¨dead-code stripping¨).

So, I would say it depends what kind of C++ linker you are using to emit the final release. Maybe you should refer to your linker documentation to get information on dead-code stripping. If it is not doing that, then it would definitely help reducing the final memory footprint of the program.

Cheers, and hope that info helps !

Answer (score 1):

It should not make any difference.

Any linker of any worth will not include anything from libraries that are not (directly or indirectly) referenced by the application, even if those libraries are specified on the command line.
The only reasons to include (a part of) a library are:
- The application uses a function or global object from the library
- A part of a library that was included to resolve some references has a reference to a function or global object of this library.

A linker does not just blindly put all the things you provide together in an application, but it makes a distinction between object files (for the application) and libraries.
The linker first collects all the object files and resolves as many references that are made between the files.
After that, the linker goes through the specified libraries and takes from each library those parts that are needed to resolve the (known) unresolved references. This may create new unresolved references due to dependencies between the libraries. Most linkers will make only a single pass over the libraries, but some may perform multiple passes to resolve all the references.
Parts of libraries that are not needed to resolve a reference are not included in the executable.

Comment: I think at best this is misleading and in my experience with the GNU toolchain for cross compiling just incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's always better to exclude the unneccessary libraries.